# Copying array values to different positions

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I managed to do the first part, which is creating a `3x2` Array and put some numbers in it. However, I cant find a good solution for the second part.
The task is:

> Copie the values from row 2 to row 1, copie the values from row 3 to row 2 and copie the values from row 1 to row 3

That's my solution:

```java
int[][] m = {{3, 7}, {4, 8}, {5, 9}};

n[0][0] = m[1][0];
n[0][1] = m[1][1];

n[1][0] = m[2][0];
n[1][1] = m[2][1];

n[2][0] = m[0][0];
n[2][1] = m[0][1];

System.out.println("");

for (int[] g : n) {
    for (int h : g)
        System.out.print(h + " ");
    System.out.println("");
}
```

I tried using a for loop but wasn't able to make it work.

Can somebody help me find a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use a `for` loop you can do something like this:

```java
int [][] m = {{3,7},{4,8},{5,9}};

int[] firstRow = m[0];

for(int i = 1; i < m.length; i++) {
  m[i-1] = m[i];
}

m[m.length-1] = firstRow;
```

In the code-example above, the first row is temporarily saved in another array with the name `firstRow`. After that i use a for loop where the counter-variable `i` is initialized with the index of the 2nd row.

Inside the `for` loop the 2nd row is moved to the first row, the 3rd row is moved to the 2nd row (and so on, if there are more rows).

When the loop has finished, the values of the temparily saved first Row are assigned to the last row of the 2-dimensional array.

---

**Advanced solution with `Collections`**

With `Collections` you can do a more compact solution for your problem:

```java
int[][] m = {{3, 7}, {4, 8}, {5, 9}};
List<int[]> rows = Arrays.asList(m);
Collections.rotate(rows, -1);
```

This will rotate the rows in your array by -1. (2nd row to 1st, 3rd row to 2nd, ..., 1st row to last row)

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to convert the array into a list using a utility method [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) and then apply method [`Collections::rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,int)) to this list to move the rows as needed.

As the list is backed up by the initial array, all the changes to the list are applied to this array as well.

Example:

```java
int [][] m = {{3,7},{4,8},{5,9}};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(m));
Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(m), -1);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(m));
```

Output:

```
[[3, 7], [4, 8], [5, 9]]
[[4, 8], [5, 9], [3, 7]]
```

---

If this solution is too advanced for a homework, a method to implement a rotated shift to the left by 1 may look as follows:

```java
public static void shiftLeftBy1(int[][] arr) {
    // copy the first row into another int[] array
    int[] copyRow = Arrays.copyOf(arr[0], arr[0].length);

    // shift the rows (no need to move each cell separately)
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }

    // set the last row to the first one
    arr[arr.length - 1] = copyRow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy an array you can use old and useful `System.arraycopy()`:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[][] m = { { 3, 7 }, { 4, 8 }, { 5, 9 } };
    int[][] n = new int[m.length][m[0].length];

    System.arraycopy(m[1], 0, n[0], 0, m[1].length);    // copy row 2 to row 1
    System.arraycopy(m[2], 0, n[1], 0, m[2].length);    // copy row 3 to row 2
    System.arraycopy(m[0], 0, n[2], 0, m[0].length);    // copy row 1 to row 3

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(m));
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(n));
}
```

Output:

```
[[3, 7], [4, 8], [5, 9]]
[[4, 8], [5, 9], [3, 7]]
```